# sql - adding time interval with skipping of certain period

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime, stored-procedures, time

I have a mySql query which adds certain interval of time to datetime field.

```
UPDATE table T 
   SET T.ending = DATE_ADD(T.ending, INTERVAL T.hours * 3600 * some_other_variable_factors SECONDS))
```

Now, I need to detect if new ending time is in between some hours (let's say 20:00 to 06:00), which should be excluded from calculation.

*Ie. if old ending is today, 19:58 and we are adding 4 minutes, new ending should be tomorrow, 06:02*

Additional difficulty is that amount of time to add can be bigger than 24 hours. *So if old ending is today, 19.00 and we are adding 24 hours, new ending should be day after  tomorrow, 15.00* (which sounds as a title of a really bad movie ;)

Is there way to achieve this in mysql? In one query? I was also thinking about stored procedures, but i do not have any experience with.

Some test data:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tt` (
      `source` datetime NOT NULL,
      `hours` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `off_start` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `off_long` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `correct` datetime NOT NULL    
    ) ENGINE=InnoDb;


    INSERT INTO `tt` (`source`, `hours`, `off_start`, `off_long`, `correct`) VALUES
    ('2010-11-11 12:00:00', 1, 20, 10, '2010-11-11 13:00:00'),
    ('2010-11-11 19:00:00', 1, 20, 10, '2010-11-12 06:00:00'),
    ('2010-11-11 19:00:00', 2, 20, 10, '2010-11-12 07:00:00'),
    ('2010-11-11 19:00:00', 3, 20, 10, '2010-11-12 08:00:00'),
    ('2010-11-11 19:00:00', 24, 20, 10, '2010-11-13 15:00:00'),
    ('2010-11-11 19:00:00', 48, 20, 10, '2010-11-15 11:00:00'),
    ('2010-11-11 19:00:00', 72, 20, 10, '2010-11-17 07:00:00');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE
        WHEN HOUR((t_ending + INTERVAL some_other_variable_factors HOUR)  - INTERVAL 20 HOUR) < 10 THEN
                t_ending + INTERVAL some_other_variable_factors HOUR + INTERVAL 10 HOUR
        ELSE
                t_ending + INTERVAL some_other_variable_factors HOUR
        END
FROM    mytable
```

`INTERVAL 20 HOUR` means your off time starts at `20:00`, `INTERVAL 10 HOUR` means it lasts for 10 hours (`20:00` till `06:00`). Adjust accordingly.

**Update:**

```
SET @hours = 54;

SELECT  CAST('2010-01-01 15:00:00' + INTERVAL @hours HOUR AS DATETIME);

--
2010-01-03 21:00:00


SELECT  CASE
        WHEN HOUR(CAST('2010-01-01 15:00:00' + INTERVAL @hours HOUR AS DATETIME)  - INTERVAL 20 HOUR) < 10 THEN
                CAST('2010-01-01 15:00:00' + INTERVAL @hours HOUR + INTERVAL 10 HOUR AS DATETIME)
        ELSE
                CAST('2010-01-01 15:00:00' + INTERVAL @hours HOUR AS DATETIME)
        END;

--
2010-01-04 07:00:00
```

Comment: and where it is 48 ? or 72? i would like to evite having enormous switch here

Comment: What is `48` or `72` and why you think they should be here?

Comment: Hours to add as interval. Because t_ending is DATETIME, not TIME

Comment: You can set `t_ending` to arbitrary datetime and `some_other_variable_factors` to arbitrary integer, including `48` and `72`.

Comment: @ts: ah, you want the off-time intervals to add up, right? Didn't get it first.

Comment: Exactly. Is there any hope, doctor?

Answer (score 2):

Was a bit tricky in a single query, but this query should work :

```
--------------
SELECT source, correct, hours_to_end, (source + INTERVAL hours_to_end HOUR) ending
FROM (
    SELECT source, correct
        , LEAST(hours, hours_to_off)
          + (((hours_left - MOD(hours_left, on_long)) / on_long) * 24
          + off_long
          + MOD(hours_left, on_long)) * overlap hours_to_end
    FROM (
        SELECT source, correct, hours, on_long, off_long, hours_to_off
            , GREATEST(0, hours - hours_to_off) hours_left
            , IF(hours - hours_to_off >= 0, 1, 0) overlap
        FROM (
            SELECT source, correct, hours, off_long
                , (24 - off_long) on_long
                , HOUR(TIMEDIFF(DATE(source) + INTERVAL off_start HOUR, source)) hours_to_off
            FROM tt
          ) t
      ) t
  ) t
--------------

+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+
| source              | correct             | hours_to_end | ending              |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 2010-11-11 12:00:00 | 2010-11-11 13:00:00 |       1.0000 | 2010-11-11 13:00:00 |
| 2010-11-11 19:00:00 | 2010-11-12 06:00:00 |      11.0000 | 2010-11-12 06:00:00 |
| 2010-11-11 19:00:00 | 2010-11-12 07:00:00 |      12.0000 | 2010-11-12 07:00:00 |
| 2010-11-11 19:00:00 | 2010-11-12 08:00:00 |      13.0000 | 2010-11-12 08:00:00 |
| 2010-11-11 19:00:00 | 2010-11-13 15:00:00 |      44.0000 | 2010-11-13 15:00:00 |
| 2010-11-11 19:00:00 | 2010-11-15 11:00:00 |      88.0000 | 2010-11-15 11:00:00 |
| 2010-11-11 19:00:00 | 2010-11-17 07:00:00 |     132.0000 | 2010-11-17 07:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

**Edit**: here is a shorter version:

```
SELECT source, correct
  , source
    + INTERVAL LEAST(hours, hours_to_off)
      + IF(hours-hours_to_off >= 0
        ,(hours-hours_to_off-MOD(hours-hours_to_off, on_long))/on_long*24
          + off_long + MOD(hours-hours_to_off, on_long)
        ,0) HOUR ending
FROM (
    SELECT source, correct, hours, off_long, (24-off_long) on_long
      , HOUR(TIMEDIFF(DATE(source)+INTERVAL off_start HOUR, source)) hours_to_off
    FROM tt
  ) t
;
```

Answer (score 1):

And this is mine:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE do_update()
BEGIN

DECLARE @offhoursperday, @hours, @days, @remaininghours INT
DECLARE @offhoursstart, @offhoursend TIME

SET @offhoursstart = CAST('22:00' AS TIME)
SET @offhoursend = CAST('06:00' AS TIME)
SET @hours = 54
SET @days = @hours / (24 - @offhoursperday)
SET @remaininghours = @hours % (24 - @offhoursperday)

UPDATE table T 
   SET T.ending =  
   CASE 
       WHEN ((HOUR(TIMEDIFF(@offhoursstart, TIME(T.ending))) + 24) % 24) < @remaininghours
       THEN DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(T.ending, INTERVAL @days DAY), INTERVAL @remaininghours HOUR)
       ELSE DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(T.ending, INTERVAL @days DAY), INTERVAL (@remaininghours + @offhoursperday) HOUR)
   END

END
```